# Want to show a fake category using htaccess for specific page present in root only

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page name **international-business-strategies.html**
For this I want to show in the url as services/international-business-strategies.html

*Note : the static page lies in the root directory only. Is this possible.
This is what I am trying to do :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule /services/international-business-strategies.html international-business-strategies.html [NC,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(international-business-strategies\.html) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /services/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^services/(international-business-strategies\.html)$ /$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your example code was almost correct, just need to use [PT] flag for rewrite rule. Here's the doc: [Apache rewrite rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html)